# How to change the default port number of the tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat

How to configure Apache Tomcat so I do not need to specify the port address in every pages?

It looks really boring to me!

Comment: Please [edit] this question and provide more detail about what you have set up and what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your port number to 80. For this go to **conf/server.xml** file in your catalina home directory. Search the server.xml file for 8080 and change it to 80. Default port of tomcat server is 8080 if you will change it to 80, you need not specify port address everytime.